# UIView not autoresizing correctly iPhone 3.5 inch vs 4 inch screen

Tags: ios6

I have a UINavigationController that has as its top UIViewController a UIViewController with a UITabBar on it.  (It is not a UITabBarController b/c I am told that Apple does not want you to push a UITabBarController on a UINavigationController).

The UITabBar controls 3 UIViewControllers.  When I run it in the simulator, the 3 UIViewControllers work for the 3.5 inch screen, or the 4 inch screen depending on how I use the simulated metrics in Interface Builder.  But I can not get the autoresizing to work on both the 3.5 and 4 inch screen.  It seems like it's either or.

This should be very simple since it's just UIAutosizeRemaskFlexibileWidth and Height.  I have tried this in code and also by playing with Interface builder, and the 3 UIViewControllers controlled by the UITabBar never fit the screen size.  I should not have to write branching code for different iphone screen sizes should I?

Comment: Agree it's infuriating.  This emergency fix saved the day ... in some situations ... in a somewhat similar situation, this saved the day .. -  (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews { // horrible fix, to make it position properly on all (most?? many??) devices! self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS 6, struts and springs have been replaced by something called Autolayout.

I suggest you take a look at this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Autolayout is optional for a reason. If it would work for everything then Apple wouldn't allow you to use struts and springs. I have situations where unfortunately Autolayout doesn't work. So the original question remains largely unanswered.

Comment: iOS 7 emulates springs and struts using autolayout. It's not because you don't know how to use autolayout that it doesn't work.